# Check if MySQL Table is empty: COUNT(*) is zero vs. LIMIT(0,1) has a result?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

This is a simple question about efficiency specifically related to the MySQL implementation. I want to just check if a table is empty (and if it is empty, populate it with the default data). Would it be best to use a statement like `` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` `` and then compare to 0, or would it be better to do a statement like `` SELECT `id` FROM `table` LIMIT 0,1 `` then check if any results were returned (the result set has next)?

Although I need this for a project I am working on, I am also interested in how MySQL works with those two statements and whether the reason people seem to suggest using `COUNT(*)` is because the result is cached or whether it actually goes through every row and adds to a count as it would intuitively seem to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should definitely go with the second query rather than the first.

When using `COUNT(*)`, MySQL is scanning at least an index and counting the records. Even if you would wrap the call in a `LEAST()` (`SELECT LEAST(COUNT(*), 1) FROM table;`) or an `IF()`, MySQL will fully evaluate `COUNT()` before evaluating further. I don't believe MySQL caches the `COUNT(*)` result when InnoDB is being used.

Your second query results in only one row being read, furthermore an index is used (assuming id is part of one). Look at the documentation of your driver to find out how to check whether any rows have been returned.
By the way, the `id` field may be omitted from the query (MySQL will use an arbitrary index):

```
SELECT 1 FROM table LIMIT 1;
```

However, I think the simplest and most performant solution is the following (as indicated in Gordon's answer):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table);
```

`EXISTS` returns `1` if the subquery returns **any** rows, otherwise `0`. Because of this semantic MySQL can optimize the execution properly.
Any fields listed in the subquery are ignored, thus `1` or `*` is commonly written.

See the [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) for more info on the `EXISTS` keyword and its use.

Comment: Marked as the accepted solution due to the better comparison and explanation.

Comment: Select exists returns a value even if the table is empty

Comment: For me right now in the table I am testing with, the second query is faster the first time you run it, before the result is cached, if the table is not empty. If the table is empty, or the result has been cached, the first query is faster. However the difference is very small in the second case, but not in the first case. If there is data in the table and the result has not been cached, then the second query is much faster. So I will go with the second one.

Comment: Actually which one is faster can depend largely on the code interacting with the database as well. The first option ended up being slightly faster for me after optimizing my code, but this will depend on your code.

Answer (score 9):

It is better to do the second method or just `exists`.  Specifically, something like:

```
if exists (select id from table)
```

should be the fastest way to do what you want.  You don't need the `limit`; the SQL engine takes care of that for you.

By the way, never put identifiers (table and column names) in single quotes.

Comment: I wanted backticks but you can't have backticks within an in-line quote here on StackOverflow. I pretty much always use backticks though to avoid keyword conflicts, is there an issue with those?

Comment: I have ended up actually using `SELECT NULL FROM table LIMIT 1` to avoid actually having to read any information from the table.

Comment: @John exactly, and `if exists (select id from table)` code does not work at all (MySQL 5.7.17)  `/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists (select ticker from wp_assets_portfolio_sessions_data)' at line 1 */`